# Mini_magick (3.6.0) Error With Bundle Update - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a bundle update and it keeps aborting at this

```
Installing mini_magick (3.6.0)
 Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.
 1/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/test/files/special! "chars'.gif
 An error occurred while installing mini_magick (3.6.0), and Bundler cannot
 continue.
 Make sure that `gem install mini_magick -v '3.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Anyone any ideas what I can do to get past this? I've installed image magick manually on my system (windows 8) but to no avail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following in your Gemfiles:

```
gem 'mini_magick', :git => 'git://github.com/minimagick/minimagick.git', :ref => '6d0f8f953112cce6324a524d76c7e126ee14f392'
```

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/145

If not works, use version 3.5.0

```
gem 'mini_magick', '3.5.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting the error

C:\Sites\horsepip>gem 'mini_magick', :git => 'git://github.com/minimagick/minima
gick.git', :ref => '6d0f8f953112cce6324a524d76c7e126ee14f392'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mini_magick,

Comment: have you install imagemagick with install development headers and libaries for C and C++ ?

Comment: No didn't need that, what I needed to do was take out the current 'mini_magick' gem from my gemfile, and add in the code above. Then run a bundle intall

Comment: I had to remove the current 'mini_magick' gem from my gemfile, and add in the code above. Then run a bundle install

Comment: I have to temporarily go to 3.5.0 until new version is released

Comment: just meant to point out that 3.7 seems to work just fine.
`gem 'mini_magick', '>= 3.7'`